# Web Scraping reviews -Flipkart

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to take out entire review of a product(remaining half of the review is display after clicking  read more. but I am still not able to do so.It is not displaying entire content of a review, which get dispalyed after clicking read more option. Below is the code , which click the readmore option and also get data from the website

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

response = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/poco-f1-graphite-black-64-gb/product-reviews/itmf8fyjyssnt25c?page=2&pid=MOBF85V7A6PXETAX")    
data = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
chromepath = r"C:\Users\Mohammed\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chromepath)
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/poco-f1-graphite-black-64-gb/product-reviews/itmf8fyjyssnt25c?page=2&pid=MOBF85V7A6PXETAX")
d = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_1EPkIx")
d.click()
title = data.find_all("p",{"class" : "_2xg6Ul"})
text1 = data.find_all("div",{"class" : "qwjRop"})
name = data.find_all("p",{"class" : "_3LYOAd _3sxSiS"})
for t2, t , t1 in zip(title,text1,name) :
    print(t2.text,'\n',t.text,'\n',t1.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the full reviews, It is necessary to click on those `READ MORE` buttons to unwrap the rest. As you have already used `selenium` in combination with `BeautifulSoup`, I've modified the script to follow the logic. The script will first click on those `READ MORE` buttons. Once it is done, it will then parse all the `titles` and `reviews` from there. You can now get the `titles` and `reviews` from multiple pages (upto 4 pages).

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

link = "https://www.flipkart.com/poco-f1-graphite-black-64-gb/product-reviews/itmf8fyjyssnt25c?page={}&pid=MOBF85V7A6PXETAX"

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #If necessary, define the chrome path explicitly
for page_num in range(1,5):
    driver.get(link.format(page_num))
    [item.click() for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1EPkIx")]
    time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    for items in soup.select("._3DCdKt"):
        title = items.select_one("p._2xg6Ul").text
        review = ' '.join(items.select_one(".qwjRop div:nth-of-type(2)").text.split())
        print(f'{title}\n{review}\n')

driver.quit()
```